# Merging 3 different dataframes based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I combine three dataframes, like below?

The primary relationship of the first two has to be based on the ID1 since it is the matching relationship between the two dataframes.

The third dataframe, the Address2 has to match in order to add in the hash

Df1:

```
Name1   Name2  Name3   Address    ID1     ID2    Own
Matt    John1  Jill     878 home   1       0     Deal
Matt    John2  Jack     879 home   2       1     Dael
```

DF2:

```
Name1   ID1   Address   Name4     Address2
Matt    1     878 home  face1     face\123
Matt    1     878 home  face2     face\345
Matt    1     878 home  face3     face\678    
Matt    2     879 home  head1     head\123
Matt    2     879 home  head2     head\345
Matt    2     879 home  head3     head\678
```

DF3:

```
Address2     Hash
face\123     abc123
face\345     cde321
face\678     efg123
head\123     123efg
head\345     efg321
head\678     acd321
```

I am trying to combine the three dataframes into one like below:

```
Name1   Name2   ID1 Address     Own    Name3    ID2 Name4   Address2    Hash
Matt    John1   1   878 home    Deal    Jill    0   face1   face\123    abc123
Matt    John1   1   878 home    Deal    Jill    0   face2   face\345    cde321
Matt    John1   1   878 home    Deal    Jill    0   face3   face\678    efg123
Matt    John2   2   879 home    Dael    Jack    1   head1   head\123    123efg
Matt    John2   2   879 home    Dael    Jack    1   head2   head\345    efg321
Matt    John2   2   879 home    Dael    Jack    1   head3   head\678    acd321
```

Between df1 and df2 the key is the Id1
Between df2 and df3 the key is the Address2

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Aren't you just merging on the column intersection here? `df1.merge(df2).merge(df3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function, some examples can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). For your specific problem, try this:

```
combined_df = df1.merge(df2, on="Id1", how="inner").merge(df3, on="Adress2", how="inner")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. Ther merge function pretty much does it for you on the columns you want to join.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([['Name1','Name2','Name3','Address','ID1','ID2','Own'],
                 ['Matt','John1','Jill','878 home','1','0','Deal'],
                 ['Matt', 'John2', 'Jack', '879 home', '2', '1', 'Dael']])

data2 = np.array([['Name1','ID1','Address','Name4','Address2'],
                 ['Matt', '1','878 home','face1',"face.123"],
                 ['Matt', '1','878 home', 'face2','face.345'],
                  ['Matt', '1','878 home', 'face3', 'face.678'],
                  ['Matt', '2', '879 home', 'head1', 'head.123'],
                  ['Matt', '2', '879 home', 'head2',  'head.345'],
                  ['Matt', '2', '879 home', 'head3', 'head.678']])
#print(data)
data3 = np.array([['Address2','Hash'],
                 ['face.123', 'abc123'],
                ['face.345','cde321'],
                 ['face.678', 'efg123'],
                ['head.123', '123efg'],
                ['head.345', 'efg321'],
                ['head.678', 'acd321']])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,:], columns=data[0,:])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2[1:,:], columns=data2[0,:])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=data3[1:,:], columns=data3[0,:])


Cdf= pd.merge(df1,df2, on='ID1', how='inner')
Ddf = pd.merge(Cdf,df3, on = 'Address2', how='inner')
print(Ddf)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your desired output, you don't seem to need *any* specification beyond the column intersection merge that is done by default.

```
>>> df1.merge(df2).merge(df3)

  Name1  Name2 Name3  Address  ID1  ID2   Own  Name4  Address2    Hash
0  Matt  John1  Jill  878 home    1    0  Deal  face1  face\123  abc123
1  Matt  John1  Jill  878 home    1    0  Deal  face2  face\345  cde321
2  Matt  John1  Jill  878 home    1    0  Deal  face3  face\678  efg123
3  Matt  John2  Jack  879 home    2    1  Dael  head1  head\123  123efg
4  Matt  John2  Jack  879 home    2    1  Dael  head2  head\345  efg321
5  Matt  John2  Jack  879 home    2    1  Dael  head3  head\678  acd321
```

Specifying singular columns to merge on as the accepted answer does will actually cause issues, as you'll have suffixed columns.

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on="ID1", how="inner").merge(df3, on="Address2", how="inner")

  Name1_x  Name2 Name3 Address_x  ID1  ID2   Own Name1_y Address_y  Name4  \
0    Matt  John1  Jill   878home    1    0  Deal    Matt   878home  face1   
1    Matt  John1  Jill   878home    1    0  Deal    Matt   878home  face2   
2    Matt  John1  Jill   878home    1    0  Deal    Matt   878home  face3   
3    Matt  John2  Jack   879home    2    1  Dael    Matt   879home  head1   
4    Matt  John2  Jack   879home    2    1  Dael    Matt   879home  head2   
5    Matt  John2  Jack   879home    2    1  Dael    Matt   879home  head3   

   Address2    Hash  
0  face\123  abc123  
1  face\345  cde321  
2  face\678  efg123  
3  head\123  123efg  
4  head\345  efg321  
5  head\678  acd321
```